# How to change an @ObservedObject variable in SceneDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a model here:

```
class Instance: ObservableObject {
    @Published var status: Status = .offline
```

which updates the following view when it changes...

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var instance = Instance()
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.instance.status.text)
    }
}
```

I want to change the value of `status` when my app opens. E.g, in `SceneDelegate`:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Change Instance variable status to .online
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

**Edit:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var auth = UserAuth()
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if auth.uid != nil { HomeView(auth: auth) } else { LoginView(auth: auth) }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this HomeView in view hierarchy relative to window root view (ContentView?)?

Comment: Added `ContentView` in edit @Asperi

Comment: I would use the environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply move your Instance into your SceneDelegate and pass a reference to your HomeView. You can pass it down directly or put your Instance into the Environment, depending on your needs. Heres an example of a direct Reference:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var instance = Instance()
    ...

    let contentView = HomeView(instance: self.instance)

    ...
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        instance.status = ...
    }
    ...
```

Change your View so it isn't initializing Instance by itself:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var instance: Instance
    var body: some View {
        Text(self.instance.status.text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood your code, in such case it is most appropriate would be to keep `auth` instance in `SceneDelegate`

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?
    let auth = UserAuth()    

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Change Instance variable status to .online
       auth.status = .online
    }
```

and use it it everywhere as `@EnvironmentObject` by inject in `ContentView().environmentObject(auth)`